# How can I get the size of an ImageView from overridden setImageBitmap()

Tags: java, android, bitmap, imageview, overriding

I've got a subclass of `ImageView` that overrides `setImageBitmap()` to intercept the bitmap given and pad it to fit the view's aspect ratio. In order to do this, I need to know the view's size, but `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` both return 0 during `setImageBitmap()`.

After seeing that `onSizeChanged()` was being called with the correct dimensions, I tried delaying the processing until then:

```java
private Bitmap pending_bitmap;

@Override public void setImageBitmap( Bitmap b ) {
    if ( getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0 ) pending_bitmap = b;
    else applyBitmap( b );
}

@Override public void onSizeChanged( int w, int h, int old_w, int old_h ) {
    if ( pending_bitmap != null ) {
        applyBitmap( pending_bitmap );
        pending_bitmap = null;
    }
}

private void applyBitmap( b ) {
    // Do some stuff that needs getWidth() and getHeight()
    super.setImageBitmap( b );
}
```

However, now `onSizeChanged()` is not being called because there is no change during `setImageBitmap()`.

I've tried passing `null` to `super.setImageBitmap()` in order to force a resize, both to no avail. Is there somewhere I can fetch `pending_bitmap` to do my processing, or some way I can force `onSizeChanged()` to be called without applying the bitmap twice?

---

**EDIT:** Also tried calling `requestLayout()` from the overridden `setImageBitmap()`. Doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: tried requestLayout ?

Comment: @pskink: Just now, yes. Question edited.

Comment: btw what do you want to achieve? maybe there is a shorter track?

Comment: you should have try onMeasure Method of View class. i hope it helps.

Comment: The bitmap is drawn via `drawBitmapMesh()` to get a 3D page-turning effect. Since images may be different shapes, they need to be padded to the same aspect ratio to prevent stretching when applied to the mesh.

Comment: and where do you call Canvas.drawBitmapMesh()? did you consider creating a custom Drawable class ?

Comment: In `onDraw()`, naturally. I could (and probably should) move most of my code to a Drawable, but it's working fine for now and I don't want to refactor forever before I get this bit nailed down. Since the Drawable's bounds would be defined by the dimensions of the View it's applied to anyway, I'd need to wait for that information to be available before creating it, so it knows how much to pad the image by when it's loaded.

Comment: @Imtiyaz: I was avoiding `onMeasure()` because I had the impression that it was bad form to override it for views that weren't doing their own layout calculations. It seems to be working reliably, though; if I can't find anything cleaner, I'll go with that.

Comment: you just have to take values form the method you do and call super.it will not take much time and it will not effect inperformence.

Comment: if you need to do custom drawing  you should use custom Drawable, Drawables are meant to draw something, that way you avoid creating cusrom View classes, but its your choice what you do

Comment: @Imtiyaz: Calling `requestLayout()` and using the values from `onMeasure()` works great. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Suppose To Use

```
OnMesure()
```

method. of View Class.

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
//when declaring vars
LinearLayout yourlayout;

//in oncreate
LinearLayout yourlayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourlayoutid);


//on size changed
LayoutParams getlay =yourlayout.getLayoutParams();



    height =getlay.height;
width=getlay.width;
```